# How to write today's date which does not change afterwards?

Tags: datetime

In latex, the command `\today` displays today's date.

Consider that I write something like: `Updated news: \today`. It appears like

> Updated news: Saturday, October 24, 2015

After a while, when I recompile the document, say 4 days later, it will say

> Updated news: Thursday, October 29, 2015

at the very same line. Is there a way to make a `\today` static? In other words, I'd like my document like a blog. When I insert a date, I want that date to stay.

How can I do this?

Comment: How can TeX know your mind? If it finds `\today` it prints today's date. If you want a static date, issue it explicitly. You can get different formats with the help of the `datetime2` package.

Comment: Therefore, I ask if there is another command that provides what I want.